Custom Meta Data in AWS S3 ObjectCreate:* event
Is it possible to add a custom field in the S3 ObjectCreate:* event? Currently, when I have metadata attached to the file, and lambda is triggered, I don't get the metadata in the event payload but have to use the S3 API to read the metadata. The reason I don't want to use the API is because I need the metadata to set the context of our application before doing any processing for login purposes.
Current Flow
File is put in S3 => Lambda A gets triggered => Lambda set the context for the flow (Context A) => Lambda Starts the Batch Job with Context A in the environment variable => Batch sets its context as Context A => Process the file => Create new file => Put files in different buckets with Context set in metadata => Different lambda gets triggered => Each lambda uses S3 API to read meta data => Each lambda set the context as Context A => Process the file... so on.
I want to remove the part where next lambda need to use S3 Api to read metadata. Metadata should be passed in the event payload

No, there is no capability to customise the contents of the event.

Closing the question as it is still not possible
